# training stops after a while

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

i'm trying to solve classification problem(cat vs dog)
in the middle of the first epoch my training got interrupted
i'm using image_dataset_from_directory to read my images:

```
train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(data_set_path+'/train' , labels='inferred',label_mode='binary', batch_size=32, image_size=(180,180), seed= 348)
val_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(data_set_path+'/val' , labels='inferred', label_mode='binary', batch_size=32, image_size=(180,180), seed= 348)
test_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(data_set_path+'/test' , labels='inferred', label_mode='binary', batch_size=32, image_size=(180,180), seed= 348)
```

and my model is as follow:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(180,180,3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = layers.Rescaling(1./255)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32,3,padding = 'same', use_bias = False)(x)
for filter_size in (32,64,128,256,512):
    residual = x
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    
    x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filter_size,3,padding= 'same' ,use_bias=False)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    
    x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filter_size,3,padding= 'same', use_bias=False)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides = 2 , padding= 'same')(x)
    
    residual = layers.Conv2D(filter_size,1,strides = 2,padding= 'same', use_bias= False) 
    (residual)
    x = layers.add([x, residual])
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs=output)
```

in the middle of first epoch i get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Input is empty.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[model_1/sequential/random_rotation/Shape/_4]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Input is empty.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_7730]
```

i would be grateful if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the case for your error but I had problems with `dogs vs cats` dataset before. A few of the images were corrupted and needed to be removed before training could proceed.

Try reading the images with opencv or `skimage` and remove the ones with exception.

Issue with dataset, https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pil-unidentifiedimageerror-in-dataloader/73577.

Comment: i will try that, thanks a lot for your help