# Not sure why getting error on CNN in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create a CNN on google collab but I am getting an error when I run it.  The error I am getting is
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Everything is fine up until the last line.  Is there a reason why I am getting an error?

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import layers

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import os

DIRECTORY = "/content/drive/MyDrive/TennisImages"
CLASS_MODE = "categorical"
COLOR_MODE = "rgb"
BATCH_SIZE = 32

training_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255, zoom_range=0.1, width_shift_range=0.05, height_shift_range=0.05, horizontal_flip = True)
validation_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator()

training_iterator = training_data_generator.flow_from_directory(DIRECTORY, class_mode = "categorical", color_mode = "rgb", batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
training_iterator.next()
validation_iterator = validation_data_generator.flow_from_directory(DIRECTORY,class_mode='categorical', color_mode='rgb',batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

def design_model(training_data):
    # sequential model
    model = Sequential()
    # add input layer with rgb image shape
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(414, 896, 3)))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))

    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.001), loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),tf.keras.metrics.AUC()],)
    # summarize model
    model.summary()
    return model

model = design_model(training_iterator)


history = model.fit(training_iterator, steps_per_epoch = 1, epochs = 5, validation_data = validation_iterator, validation_steps = 1)
```

The error message is:
How can I edit my code so that I can fix this error?  Thank you.

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-fcce5cac1884> in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 history = model.fit(training_iterator, steps_per_epoch = 1, epochs = 5, validation_data = validation_iterator, validation_steps = 1)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_3/flatten_3/Reshape' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1233, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2855, in run_cell
      raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3058, in run_cell_async
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-19-fcce5cac1884>", line 4, in <module>
      history = model.fit(training_iterator, steps_per_epoch = 1, epochs = 5, validation_data = validation_iterator, validation_steps = 1)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 452, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/flatten.py", line 96, in call
      return tf.reshape(inputs, flattened_shape)
Node: 'sequential_3/flatten_3/Reshape'
Input to reshape is a tensor with 984064 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1435008
     [[{{node sequential_3/flatten_3/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4377]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Argument Error / Graph Execution Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153492/invalid-argument-error-graph-execution-error)

Comment: Always include the complete error message, without it we cannot help you.

Comment: `Input to reshape is a tensor with 984064 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1435008` seems pretty clear.

Comment: Maybe you should add  `target_size=(414, 896)` to `flow_from_directory`

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a dataset to the `fit` method, it will not check the image sizes. So they go through the `conv` layers without problems (they accept any image size), but at the `Flatten` layer there will be a problem, because it expects exactly 1435008 numbers based on the the layers before and the `input_shape`. So it fails at the flatten layer. You can resolve this problem by providing images of the correct size, add `target_size=(414, 896)` to `flow_from_directory`:

```
training_iterator = training_data_generator.flow_from_directory(DIRECTORY, target_size=(414, 896), class_mode = "categorical", color_mode = "rgb", batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
training_iterator.next()
validation_iterator = validation_data_generator.flow_from_directory(DIRECTORY, target_size=(414, 896), class_mode='categorical', color_mode='rgb',batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```