# Where should the LSTM be placed in my CNN for NLP and how do I connect it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have a problem. I would like to use LSTM in my 1D-CNN to get an improvement in my NLP task.
The problem is that I don't know exactly where to put the LSTM. I have found the following.

```
A CNN LSTM can be defined by adding CNN layers on the front end followed by LSTM layers with a Dense layer on the output.
```

(Source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/)

However, if I set it up like this (see code below), I get the following error

```py
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 128)
```

This is because LSTM expects a 3D input array. Is there an option to fix this error and use LSTM at this position? Or should it be somewhere else?

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dense, GlobalMaxPooling1D, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, LSTM, Bidirectional, Lambda, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D

model_lstm = Sequential()

model_lstm.add(
        Embedding(vocab_size
                ,embed_size
                ,weights = [embedding_matrix] #Supplied embedding matrix created from glove
                ,input_length = maxlen
                ,trainable=False)
         )
model_lstm.add(SpatialDropout1D(rate = 0.4))
model_lstm.add(Conv1D(256, 7, activation="relu"))
model_lstm.add(MaxPooling1D())
#model_lstm.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu"))
model_lstm.add(MaxPooling1D())
model_lstm.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model_lstm.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3,return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_lstm.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model_lstm.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
print(model_lstm.summary())
```

Complete Code

```py
print("Train shape : ",train_X2.shape)
print("Test shape : ",test_X2.shape)

## Tokenize the sentences
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_unique_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(train_X2))
train_X2 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_X2)
test_X2 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_X2)

## Pad the sentences 
train_X = pad_sequences(train_X2, maxlen=maxlen)
test_X = pad_sequences(test_X2, maxlen=maxlen)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

#label encoding
le = LabelEncoder()
train_y = le.fit_transform(train_y2.tolist())
test_y = le.transform(test_y2.tolist())

#one hot encoding
train_y = to_categorical(train_y)
test_y = to_categorical(test_y)

# Word2Vec as pretrained embedding
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
NUM_WORDS=20000
word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r'./input/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

EMBEDDING_DIM=300
vocabulary_size=min(len(word_index)+1,NUM_WORDS)
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocabulary_size, EMBEDDING_DIM))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i>=NUM_WORDS:
        continue
    try:
        embedding_vector = word_vectors[word]
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    except KeyError:
        embedding_matrix[i]=np.random.normal(0,np.sqrt(0.25),EMBEDDING_DIM)

del(word_vectors)

from keras.layers import Embedding
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            trainable=True)

from keras.layers import Embedding
EMBEDDING_DIM=300
vocabulary_size=min(len(word_index)+1,NUM_WORDS)

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM)

# CNN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try removing the GlobalMaxPooling1D layer which reduces your tensor to 2D. For example try copy and run this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dense, GlobalMaxPooling1D, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, LSTM, Bidirectional, Lambda, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D

model_lstm = Sequential()

model_lstm.add(
        Embedding(vocab_size
                ,embed_size
                ,weights = [embedding_matrix] #Supplied embedding matrix created from glove
                ,input_length = maxlen
                ,trainable=False)
         )
model_lstm.add(SpatialDropout1D(rate = 0.4))
model_lstm.add(Conv1D(256, 7, activation="relu"))
model_lstm.add(MaxPooling1D())
#model_lstm.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu"))
model_lstm.add(MaxPooling1D())
model_lstm.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, return_sequences=False))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_lstm.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model_lstm.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
print(model_lstm.summary())
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.
Could you tell me why I have to remove the layer? And does it fit where the LSTM is, or should it be somewhere else?

Comment: Because `GlobalMaxPooling1D` reduces your 3D tensor to a 2D tensor by selecting the max value(s) across the last dimension. A `LSTM` layer requires a 3D tensor as input. Regarding your second question, I think you should just experiment with several combinations and see what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks! :)
Training is cancelled after the first epoch with `InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:`. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153492/invalid-argument-error-graph-execution-error). Do you still need to adjust the size?

Comment: That error can mean a lot..You would have to show the whole stack trace

Answer (score 1):

**Remain all your works and make senses that create labels without local dictionary or quick search from single line string.** All remains you don't need to review forcefully handling continue.

I try to make it without creating a tokenizer when flat mapping and labels create from separated sources and single line string the song lyrics.

Sample: This way is easy for you not to have quick words mapping you can insert manually, see from the sourcecodes you need to filled the number of quick words search.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
input_word = tf.constant(' \'Cause it\'s easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Oh, easy as an ice cream sundae ')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word) )
window_size = 6
dataset = dataset.map( lambda x:  tft.sliding_window(x, width=window_size, axis=0) ).flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
dataset = dataset.batch(1)

list_word = []
label = []
vocab = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "I", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_" ]
vocab_hot = [ "ice" ]
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
layer_hot = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab_hot)

for example in dataset.take(200):
    sequences_mapping_string = layer(example[0])
    sequences_mapping_string = tf.constant( sequences_mapping_string, shape=(1, 6) )
    list_word.append(sequences_mapping_string.numpy())

    sequences_mapping_string = tf.reduce_sum(layer_hot( example[0][0] + example[0][1] + example[0][2] ))
    sequences_mapping_string = tf.constant( sequences_mapping_string, shape=(1, 1) )
    
    label.append(sequences_mapping_string.numpy())

list_word = tf.constant(list_word, shape=(200, 1, 6, 1), dtype=tf.int64)
label = tf.constant(label, shape=(200, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_word, label))

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyLSTMLayer( tf.keras.layers.LSTM ):
    def __init__(self, units, return_sequences, return_state):
        super(MyLSTMLayer, self).__init__( units, return_sequences=True, return_state=False )
        self.num_units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_units])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)                       

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['accuracy'] >= 0.97 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
mycustomlayer = MyLSTMLayer( 64, True, False )
mycustomlayer_2 = MyLSTMLayer( 16, True, False )

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(6, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 128, input_length=1),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 6, 128 )),
    tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D( rate = 0.4 ),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 6, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(strides=1, pool_size=1),
    ### LSTM
    mycustomlayer,
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 1, 1, 64 )),
    tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D( size=(4, 4), data_format=None, interpolation='nearest' ),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 8, 16 )),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
    ### LSTM
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 1, 16 )),
    mycustomlayer_2,
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4),
    
], name="MyModelClassification")

model.build()
model.summary()


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    learning_rate=0.000001,
    momentum=0.5,
    nesterov=True,
    name='SGD',
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=3, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

Output:

```
Model: "MyModelClassification"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, 6, 1, 128)         128000

 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 6, 128)            0

 spatial_dropout1d (SpatialD  (None, 6, 128)           0
 ropout1D)

 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 1, 32)             24608

 max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D  (None, 1, 32)            0
 )

 my_lstm_layer (MyLSTMLayer)  (None, 1, 64)            2048

 reshape_1 (Reshape)         (None, 1, 1, 64)          0

 up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D  (None, 4, 4, 64)         0
 )

 conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 4, 2, 16)          3088

 reshape_2 (Reshape)         (None, 8, 16)             0

 max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 4, 16)            0
 1D)

 global_max_pooling1d (Globa  (None, 16)               0
 lMaxPooling1D)

 reshape_3 (Reshape)         (None, 1, 16)             0

 my_lstm_layer_1 (MyLSTMLaye  (None, 1, 16)            256
 r)

 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 1, 16)             0

 dense (Dense)               (None, 1, 128)            2176

 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 128)               0

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 516

=================================================================
Total params: 160,692
Trainable params: 160,692
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/3
2022-10-14 16:33:44.261736: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
200/200 [==============================] - 3s 5ms/step - loss: 0.3487 - accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 2/3
200/200 [==============================] - 1s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2064 - accuracy: 0.9850
```