# My linear regression model runs fine on google colab but throws an error on my jupyter notebook when i run it locally on my macbook m1 pro

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

i am trying to run a linear regression model on my macbook m1 pro using python and tensorflow.The tensorflow i am using is tensorflow metal for apple silicon with all its dependencies installed but its giving an error saying "NotFoundError: Graph execution error:" when i run my code.But when i use the same code on google colab it works just fine.I have tried everything from reinstalling jupyter notebook to reinstalling tensorflow.All my libraries are up to date as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

# Load data from Excel file
file_path = '/Users/ayushanand/Documents/Data Farming/New Data/Data_Final_Features.xlsx'
print(file_path)
data = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Merge', index_col=0)

# Split data into features and target
X = data.iloc[:, :-1]
y = data.iloc[:, -1]

# Split data into training and testing sets
train_size = int(0.8 * len(data))
X_train, X_test = X[:train_size], X[train_size:]
y_train, y_test = y[:train_size], y[train_size:]

# Define the linear regression model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), activation='linear')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)

# Evaluate the model's accuracy on the training set
train_loss = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
print('Training loss:', train_loss)

# Evaluate the model's accuracy on the testing set
test_loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Testing loss:', test_loss)
```

```
/Users/ayushanand/Documents/Data Farming/New Data/Data_Final_Features.xlsx
2023-03-22 05:47:31.804968: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2023-03-22 05:47:31.852556: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x1129b0ef0
2023-03-22 05:47:31.852588: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x1129b0ef0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 27
     24 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
     26 # Train the model
---> 27 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)
     29 # Evaluate the model's accuracy on the training set
     30 train_loss = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'StatefulPartitionedCall' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 725, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 513, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 502, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 729, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 540, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3016, in _run_cell
      result = runner(coro)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3221, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3400, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3460, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "/var/folders/tb/pxp_kc851ts4tywxh3w8klgw0000gn/T/ipykernel_1905/1844586263.py", line 27, in <module>
      model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1027, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 527, in minimize
      self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1140, in apply_gradients
      return super().apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 634, in apply_gradients
      iteration = self._internal_apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1166, in _internal_apply_gradients
      return tf.__internal__.distribute.interim.maybe_merge_call(
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1216, in _distributed_apply_gradients_fn
      distribution.extended.update(
    File "/Users/ayushanand/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1211, in apply_grad_to_update_var
      return self._update_step_xla(grad, var, id(self._var_key(var)))
Node: 'StatefulPartitionedCall'
could not find registered platform with id: 0x1129b0ef0
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_999]
```

Comment: All libraries are up to date? But you are using Python 3.9?

Comment: Did you see [this post on the Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722873)? In expanded form [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75357677/8508004).

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes...all libraries are up to date and i am using python 3.9.16

Comment: My point is that python 3.11 is the latest

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Wayne i tried that but it doesn't solve the problem.As mentioned in the comment of the answer you sent, CyberPlayerOne in the mentioned post says their issue was solved when TF was downgraded to 2.10.0 from 2.11.0.But my tf only seem to work when its on 2.11.0, after downgrade it using pip or conda to 2.10.0 i am getting error not found on my code,import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)                                                                                                                NotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

Comment: What you describe experiencing doesn't mean your code wouldn't work with tensorflow by downgrading, but that you haven't managed to downgrade and have it appear installed if it is failing to import now. (I'm guessing that from what you posted at the end but it is cut off. Easier to put the whole traceback in a code snippet or gist somewhere and past a link.) Anyway, that seems to be the same issue. None of the other leads on that page have helped any?