# How can I fix "Invalid Argument Error" with CNN using tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, image-classification

This is my first time using machine learning and am very new to it so any advice/input is helpful!

I am trying to use image classification to measure fiber alignment to the nearest degree. MATLab generates my training data and stores images in folders corresponding to alignment degree in "training_data".

This is the code I am using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Define the CNN model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1024, 768, 1)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(2)
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                            metrics=['accuracy'])

# Set up the data generator for image augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   rotation_range=20,
                                   width_shift_range=0.1,
                                   height_shift_range=0.1,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

# Load the training data from directory
train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:/Users/atlgu/Desktop/CNT Research/ML Image Analysis/train_images/training_data',
    target_size=(1024, 768),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='input')

# Train the model
model.fit(train_data, epochs=10)
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at (most recent call last):
```

I asked chatGPT what the reason is, and it sounds like its an issue with my training data format not matching the expected format. I've checked size and grayscale but I am not sure what else to check.

I thought it might be one of these:

[-] size of my images

[-] format of my images (#color channels?)

[-] format of training data directory

Comment: see, if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153492/invalid-argument-error-graph-execution-error

Comment: The error is incomplete, always include the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can happen if your input_shape is too big or your batch_size is too high, in this case your input_shape is (1024, 768, 1), I think this is too big.

Try to shrink it to for example (224,224,1).

Comment: Another thing, you have classification problem right? You should use sparse_categorical_crossentropy instead of MeanSquaredError.