# Graph execution error when using model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, unet-neural-network

I am a beginner for machine learning, and currently trying the retina-unet. There's a couple errors when processing model.fit

```
model.fit(patches_imgs_train, patches_masks_train, epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Data size:
patches_imgs_train: (190000,1,48,48)
patches_masks_train: (190000,2304,2)

I got the error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
```

Second error:

```
Detected at node 'gradient_tape/model/conv2d_10/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2195, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2177, in main
      globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1489, in run
      return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1496, in _exec
      pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
      exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\Desktop\EFRI\Data\AI\Unet\retina-unet-master\retinaNN_training.py", line 194, in <module>
      model.fit(patches_imgs_train, patches_masks_train, epochs=N_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1742, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1338, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1322, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1303, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1084, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\optimizers\optimizer.py", line 543, in minimize
      grads_and_vars = self.compute_gradients(loss, var_list, tape)
    File "C:\Users\pnl71\PycharmProjects\Unetsegmentation\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\optimizers\optimizer.py", line 276, in compute_gradients
      grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)
Node: 'gradient_tape/model/conv2d_10/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput'
Conv2DCustomBackpropInputOp only supports NHWC.
     [[{{node gradient_tape/model/conv2d_10/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2002]
```

Not sure how to fix this...

Comment: The solutions posted in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153492/invalid-argument-error-graph-execution-error) might be useful.

Comment: you have 190000 (N) samples with 1 channel (C) and height (H) of 48 and width (W) of 48, so your data is sorted NCHW, but your data is required to be sorted NHWC.  I do not know whether you just installed some package, wrote the code accordingly to some source or did something in-between but when you use Conv2D, you should read the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D -> "data_format: Note that the channels_first format is currently not supported by TensorFlow on CPU" Maybee that is relevant for your project.