# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm having this unexpected error, while running the EfficientNet training code.
I am not understanding the root cause of error.

Tried this following code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB7
img_size = (200,200)

base_model = EfficientNetB7(
    include_top = False,
    input_shape = img_size + (3,),
    weights = 'imagenet'
)

for layer in base_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = True

model = base_model.output
model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model)
model = Dropout(0.4)(model)
model = Dense(4, activation = "softmax")(model)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = model)

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001), metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()

callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint("model_wt.hdf5", monitor = 'val_loss', mode = "min", verbose = 1, save_best_only = True),
             ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss', factor = 0.3, patience = 2, verbose = 1, mode = 'min', min_lr = 0.00000001)]

history = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 64), validation_data = (x_val,y_val), epochs = 50, callbacks = callbacks)
```

got this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-701d4fd202fc> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 64), validation_data = (x_val,y_val), epochs = 50, callbacks = callbacks)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51   try:
     52     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None
```

I am running this on Google Colaboratory.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Argument Error / Graph Execution Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153492/invalid-argument-error-graph-execution-error)